# Trouble using Japanese characters in-game

Tags: winning-post-9

Recently I purchased Winning Post 9 on Steam for the pc. I had gotten it for ps4 earlier this year, and had no issues, but for the last two years I can't seem to input a name using Japanese IME, and now I'm stuck at that screen. 
The issue is that the game says they need to be full width letters, even though they are full width.

I'm pretty sure I'm doing everything right. Any help would be appreciated.

I will link to a video of the problem in a few minutes: I'm making it and uploading to Youtube shortly.

Comment: [The game](https://store.steampowered.com/app/939700) isn't even available in English-speaking regions. You'll probably have better luck in a 日本語 forum

Comment: Its available from play asia or amazon.  Thanks.   Will check it out